# Difference between opaque and hierarchical URI?

Tags: java, uri

What is the Difference between **opaque** and **hierarchical URI** in context of `java networking` ?

Answer (score 28):

A typical example of an opaque uri is a mail to url `mailto:a@b.com`. They differ from a hierarchical uri in that they don't describe a path to a resource.

Therefore a Uri that is opaque returns `null` for `getPath`.

Some examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printUriInfo(URI.create("mailto:a@b.com"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("http://example.com"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("http://example.com/path"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("scheme://example.com"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("scheme:example.com"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("scheme:example.com/path"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("path"));
    printUriInfo(URI.create("/path"));
}

private static void printUriInfo(URI uri) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Uri [%s]", uri));
    System.out.println(String.format(" is %sopaque", uri.isOpaque() ? "" : "not "));
    System.out.println(String.format(" is %sabsolute", uri.isAbsolute() ? "" : "not "));
    System.out.println(String.format(" Path [%s]", uri.getPath()));
}
```

Prints:

```
Uri [mailto:a@b.com]
 is opaque
 is absolute
 Path [null]
Uri [http://example.com]
 is not opaque
 is absolute
 Path []
Uri [http://example.com/path]
 is not opaque
 is absolute
 Path [/path]
Uri [scheme://example.com]
 is not opaque
 is absolute
 Path []
Uri [scheme:example.com]
 is opaque
 is absolute
 Path [null]
Uri [scheme:example.com/path]
 is opaque
 is absolute
 Path [null]
Uri [path]
 is not opaque
 is not absolute
 Path [path]
Uri [/path]
 is not opaque
 is not absolute
 Path [/path]
```

Answer (score 8):

This is explained by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#isOpaque--) for the URI class:

> *"A URI is opaque if, and only if, it is absolute and its scheme-specific part does not begin with a slash character ('/'). **An opaque URI has a scheme, a scheme-specific part, and possibly a fragment; all other components are undefined.**"*

The "components" it is referring to are the values returned by various `URI` getters.

Apart from that the "difference" comprises the inherent difference between opaque and hierarchical URIs as per the relevant specifications; e.g.

- [RFC 3986 - "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Those differencese are in no way Java specific.