# DIfference between Uri.fromParts and Uri.parse?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, uri

I'm creating an Intent for Android, to send e-mails.

And I'm getting confused about the behavior of Uri.fromParts.

Mi code:
This works fine!

```
uri=Uri.parse(
  "mailto:" + toAddress +
    (subject != null ?
      ("?" + "subject=" + Uri.encode(subject)) :
      "")
```

The previous work fine, and create an Uri in the form `mailto:john@doe.com?subject=Test`

But if I try to use Uri.from parts, with this sample:

```
uriBuilder=Uri.fromParts("mailto",toAddress,null).buildUpon();
if (subject!=null) {
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("subject",subject);
}
uri=uriBuilder.build();
```

I get an error. The final uri is `mailto:?subject=Test`

The intermediate is correct, but when I use appendQueryParameter, it removes the content after the mailto scheme.

Do you know why? Which is the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Uri#fromParts()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromParts(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Creates an opaque Uri from the given components. Encodes the ssp which means this method cannot be used to create hierarchical URIs.

When you call `buildUpon()` on this, the `Builder` contains the scheme, scheme-specific part (ssp) and the fragment (null in your case).

`appendQueryParameter()` then turns the `Builder` to a hierarchical one, deleting the opaque ssp data.

I don't think there's a "canonical" way. Just don't mix hierarchical and opaque builders.

For details on what happens under the hood, read the [source](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/Uri.java).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It add a new concept (at least, new for me): The hierarchical vs. non-hierarchical Uris. But, accepting this, why, if appendQueryParameter is going to corrupt the non-hierachical ones, why doesn't generate an exception. Have I to open an incident?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635991/difference-between-opaque-and-hierarchical-uri