# Why opaque URI shall not begin with single slash ('/'), not double-slash ('//')? Any practical example of URI with just one slash?

Tags: java, uri

> A URI is opaque if, and only if, **it is absolute** and its
>   scheme-specific part **does not begin with a slash character ('/')**. An
>   opaque URI has a scheme, a scheme-specific part, and possibly a
>   fragment; all other components are undefined.

But all URI/URL having a protocol (scheme) I always see **two** slashes (like `http://` ).

Is there a practically used example of an URI or URL with a single / after protocol?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635991/difference-between-opaque-and-hierarchical-uri

Comment: `file:/home/vgr` is a valid hierarchical URI.

Comment: @VGR I'd accept this as answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not every hierarchical URI scheme requires an authority component.  Most notably, the `file:` scheme does not need one.  `file:/home/vgr` is a valid URI.